# Page Content In Wordpress Is Not Displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme from scratch and I think I'm having problems with my page.php file. When I go into the admin panel, add a new page and fill out the content I want then view the page I only see the title of the page while the rest is blank. For some reason the content of the page is not displaying.

The code in my page.php file is..

```
    <?php /*
    Template Name: Page Template
    */

    get_header(); ?>

    <div class="page">

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <hr>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I only get to see up to the horizontal rule and then the footer but everything else in between is blank. Am I maybe missing something in my functions.php file?

Comment: Could you also post the code in your content template? It could be called `content-page.php` or `content.php`. If none exist then you probably want to use `the_content();` instead.

Comment: I do not have a content page and I have tried the_content(); but I still get the same results.

Comment: I'm not sure this is doing what you want it to do.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part
You should have a content-page.php file with something written in it before the middle loop will produce any output.  Try creating that page with something simple, like an echo statement, just to see if you get some output.

Comment: Ok, then remove the entire `get_template_part()` line and replace it with `<?php the_content(); ?>`. If this doesn't work there's either no page content to output or you have an error somewhere else. Read here about enabling the drug mode: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a piece of code in my functions.php file.

```
    function PLEASE_the_tags($content='') {
       global $post;
       $html.="<div class='tags'>\n";
       $html.="<a href='#' rel='tag'>".$post_the_tags."</a>\n";
       $html.="</div?\n";
       $content.=$html;
       return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'get_the_tag_list');
```

After I removed this, the content started showing again. I have no idea how this caused the problem but thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `var_dump( get_template_part('content', 'page') )` or even `var_dump(the_post())`, you should get important debugging info...